# Windows Server 2003 clr.dll library in framework v.4.0

Tags: asp.net, dll, crash, windows-server-2003

For more days on my Windows Server 2003 with ASP NET Framework 4.0 ( in a few months change on Windows Server 2008 ASP NET Framework 4.5 ) when run application asp net I have this error exception unknown software:

[image]

Using the software DebugDiag 1.1 (x86) it seems that the problem is a framework library **clr.dll**

[image]

On the thread 27 I see:

[image]

On the thread 29 I see:

[image]

Anybody know how can I resolve this?

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**###Edit no. 1**

I have installed in this machine the software: [DebugDiagx86.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336)

This is the output in Visual Studio 2013:

```
<DebugDiag MaxClrExceptionDetailsPerSecond="30" 
           MaxClrExceptionStacksPerSecond="20" 
MaxClrExceptionStacksPerExceptionType="10" 
MaxClrExceptionStacksTotal="100" MaxNativeExceptionStacksPerSecond="30">
<Rules>
  <Rule TargetType="PROCESS" TargetName="w3wp.exe" UFEActionType="" UFEActionLimit="0" MaxDumpLimit="10" MatchingLeakRuleKey="" PageheapType="" 
        RuleType="CRASH" Active="TRUE" RuleName="Crash rule for all instances of w3wp.exe" 
DumpPath="C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\Crash rule for all instances of w3wp.exe"><Exceptions>
  <Exception ExceptionCode="E0434352" ExceptionName="CLR (.NET) 4.x Exception" ExceptionData="" ExceptionData2="" 
             ExceptionDataCheck="FALSE" ActionType="LOGSTACK" ActionLimit="1"/></Exceptions><Events/><Breakpoints/></Rule></Rules></DebugDiag>
```

Comment: If possible find a Windows 7 machine with only .NET 4.0 installed, and then install DebugDiag 2.0 on that to analyze the same dump, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933 That should print out the managed call stack instead of native, which reveals you more info on this exception. It is very likely to be an unhandled exception in your code.

Comment: @LexLi thank you for reply, but I don't have Windows 7 machine available,

Comment: @LexLi Please see **###Edit no. 1** in my first question-